# Meta participation

Tags: support

I was looking at the Moderator Election page for the last election, and I noticed that each candidate has a Meta participation section, showing how many times their question or answer has be up/down voted.

Is there a way to get this information for any user normally?

Comment: Nope, this was made specifically for the elections AFAIK

Comment: Why was it not standardized, just out of curiosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a concise way to find that info, other than what you can summarize from your profile. You could probably pull it from [the API](http://api.meta.superuser.com/1.0/usage) or [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) somehow, but it's not built-in.